# Cambiar la estructura de datos

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente array de string

```
var miArray = ['item1' , 'item2' ]
```

me gustaria convertirlo en

```
var items = [
    {
        "name" : "item1"
    },
    {
        "name" : "item2"
    }
]
```

He leido algo sobre la funcion map pero no entiendo muy bien.. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado

```
miArray.map(function(tag) {
    return { "name": tag };
});
```

Comment: pues el resultado que yo veo por consola es similar mas no igual al que tu planteas querer obtener

Comment: me he formulado mal la pregunta entonces, lo que necesitaba era convertir mi array de string en un array de key : value ... Gracias por tu tiempo